# Python: Check if vertex is on camera field of view

Tags: python, rendering, camera, vertices

[image]

Suppose I have the following camera perspective.

As you can see some of the Cube vertices are visible from the camera, others are not.

Is there a way from python to detect if a certain vertex is in the camera field of view or not?

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14711/does-cycles-use-a-camera-frustum-check

Answer (score 3):

```py
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector
from bpy_extras.object_utils import world_to_camera_view

scene = bpy.context.scene
cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
mesh = obj.data
mat_world = obj.matrix_world
cs, ce = cam.data.clip_start, cam.data.clip_end

assert obj.mode == "EDIT"
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)

for v in bm.verts:
    co_ndc = world_to_camera_view(scene, cam, mat_world @ v.co)
    #check wether point is inside frustum
    if (0.0 < co_ndc.x < 1.0 and
        0.0 < co_ndc.y < 1.0 and
        cs < co_ndc.z <  ce):
        v.select = True
    else:
        v.select = False

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh, False, False)
```

Comment: I am trying to run the above code in Blender 2.8, but it throws errors.  Is an update possible?

Comment: **For Blender 2.8+** replace the last line with `bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)`. Make sure the object is in *Edit* mode.