# Blender 2.8 (Python) - how to put mesh into edit mode

Tags: python, mesh, bmesh

For this line of code:

```
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
```

I am encountering the error 'ValueError: The mesh must be in editmode'

I am not certain how to fix this problem.  For context, I am adapting the code solution at the bottom of [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32975/python-check-if-vertex-is-on-camera-field-of-view) post, which was for an earlier version of Blender.  My full code is here:

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
mesh = obj.data
mat_world = obj.matrix_world
cs, ce = cam.data.clip_start, cam.data.clip_end
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')            
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)          
for v in bm.verts:
    co_ndc = world_to_camera_view(scene, cam, mat_world * v.co)
    #check wether point is inside frustum
    if (0.0 < co_ndc.x < 1.0 and 0.0 < co_ndc.y < 1.0 and cs < co_ndc.z <  ce):
        v.select = True
    else:
        v.select = False

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh, False, False)
```

Comment: What do you'd like to do? How about `bm = bmesh.from_mesh(mesh)`? ... from the *Text Editor > Python > Bmesh Simple*.

Comment: @brockmann ... I edited my question to include the full block of code.  Separately, ```bm=bmesh.from_mesh(mesh)``` throws the error "module 'bmesh' has no attribute 'from_mesh'"

Comment: I don't get any error. I'd recommend starting by using the template @vndep Even the old script is still working, just replace `*` with `@`  and run it....

Comment: How about entering edit mode before you copy the `context scene`

Comment: That's the solution.  It was a matter of adapting the code to a larger program and working out mode interactions.  Thanks!