# Selecting vertices only visible in camera frustum

Tags: python, selection-tools, geometry

I want to select the vertices which are visible in camera frustum and delete the rest which are either occluded or not in camera frustum. I don't want to do it manually but with a python script. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ans may you want:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32975/python-check-if-vertex-is-on-camera-field-of-view

Comment: I have tried this method. The problem is, it also selects those vertices which are not visible to camera i.e. the occluded ones. But I need to select only those which are visible to camera.